Trigonometric Pyramidology
Problem. A pyramidologist makes a round trip on a pyramid along the sketched path, i.e., from one corner of the base to the middle of the next edge, from there to the top of the pyramid, and then directly back to the starting point. The pyramid has a square base, and the height is equal to half of the side length of the base. Moving at a constant speed of 22 m/min, the pyramidologist takes 28 minutes for the entire trip. How high is the pyramid?
Question: I tried to solve this exercise by relating similar triangles, but I haven’t gotten far. Can someone provide me with a hint on how to start? I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Let the center point of the base be called $A$, the top be called $B$ and the center of a given side of the square base $C$. Find all the side lengths of the triangle $ABC$ using Pythagoras. Now let the two corners to the left and right of $C$ be called $D$ and $E$. Find the sides of triangle $BDE$, again you can use Pythagoras. Now all that's left is to bisect line $BE$  to find your final length $x$, using the cosine rule. With this in hand, the total distance  is $|BE|+|BE|/2+x$.

@AP Thank you for your answer. I’m not sure how the Pythagorean theorem can be applied in this case, as it seems one side is still missing. Could you please elaborate?

In the case of the triangle $ABC$, you know $|BA|=|CB|=h$ and the line $AB$ is perpendicular to $CB$. In the case of triangle $BDE$, take the triangle $BCE$ as we know $|CE|=h$ and we found $|BC|$ in the last step. Furthermore, you should convince yourself that that the angle $BCE$ is a right angle.

@AP Okay, but in that case, you are assuming it's a right pyramid.

If it's not a right pyramid, I don't believe you have enough information to solve it.

Assuming a right pyramid, then this can be solved using a double application of the cosine rule
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos\theta$$
If the length of the edge diagonal is $\sqrt3$ and the base length is $2$, then
$$2^2=\sqrt3^2+\sqrt3^2-2\sqrt3\sqrt3\cos\theta$$
$$4=6(1-\cos\theta)$$
$$\cos\theta=\frac13$$
Then, using the bisected edge, where $d$ is the long line, we have
$$d^2=\sqrt3^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^2-2\sqrt3\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cos\theta$$
$$d^2=3+\frac34-3\cos\theta$$
$$d^2=\frac{15}4-1$$
$$d^2=\frac{11}4$$

Let $ABCD$ is the base, $O$ is the center of the base and $E$ is the vertex of the pyramid. $AO=h\sqrt{2}, EO=h, EA=EB=h\sqrt{3}$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $EB$. We can find median $AM$ using Apollonius Theorem:
$AM=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2EA^2+2AB^2-EB^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3h^2+8h^2}=\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}h$
Can you finish?

Note: The main assumption is that the pyramid is a right pyramid and all medians of the lateral faces drawn to a lateral edge are congruent.


Thank you for your explanation. However, I’m a bit confused about why $EO=h$. Doesn’t the vertex of the pyramid not necessarily have to be directly above the center of the base?

I assume the pyramid is a right pyramid, otherwise the problem is not solvable.
